# Why are the icons not showing up on my Ant Design sider?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

```
<Sider collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed} onCollapse={this.onCollapse} breakpoint="md">
          <Menu
          theme="dark"
          mode="inline"
          defaultSelectedKeys={['10']}
          style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
          >                            
          <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<LoginOutlined />}><Link to="/login">Login</Link></Menu.Item>
```

This is what my Sider code looks like. But still, the icon doesn't show on the Sider. This code works perfectly on CodeSandBox. Using the latest version of Chrome.
[image: icon doesn't show]

Even the collapsed form doesn't show icons.

[image: doesn't show the icon]

Please help.

Edits: 
1. CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-ant-design-demo-zkpcs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
2. package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://exampple.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "antd": "^4.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "customize-cra": "^0.9.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.23",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "less": "^3.11.1",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-ga": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tsutil": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "netlify deploy",
    "deployprod": "netlify deploy --prod",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.7.0",
    "npm": "6.13.6"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide sandbox link?

Comment: Hi, I added the link in the edit section. Here it is anyway https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-ant-design-demo-zkpcs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you show your package.json or it's the same as in codesandbox. If you updated from previous version, try to remove node_modules and package-lock.json. Then run npm install @KshitijSinha

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added the package.json above.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to fix it was update from "antd" version 4.0.0 to the latest version 4.6.3